# Extract raw 'a variable from 'a option

Tags: ocaml

I am working with a simple function that is supposed to extract the value of `'a` from an object of type `'a option`. I have seen examples here that look like what I have written, but OCaml is confusing this for a function that takes `'a option option` and I'm not sure why.

```
let extract_x x = match x with
  | Some state -> state
  | None -> None
```

OCaml's interpretation as seen in utop: `val extract_x : 'a option option -> 'a option = <fun>`

Comment: That's because of `| None -> None`. What type did you expect `extract_x` to have?

Comment: The input has type `state option` and `type state = string`. It could be a `string` or it could be `None`. The return value should be the raw `state` without the `option` keyword or `None` if the input was `None` in the first place.

Comment: I didn't ask you for a prose description. What type did you expect `extract_x` to have?

Comment: `extract_x` should have type `string`

Comment: It can't have type `string`. Strings don't have arguments and cannot be called; your `extract_x` has an `x` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s pretend we are the (or rather, *an*) ocaml typechecker and we want to decide the type of your value `extract_x`

```
let extract_x x = ...
```

Ok so here we know that the type of `extract_x` must be a function, `_ -> _`. Let’s call the currently unknown input type `a` and the output type `z`, then the variable `x` has type `a`:

```
extract_x : a -> z
x : a
... : z
```

Let’s look deeper:

```
let extract_x x = match x with
  | p1 -> v1
  | p2 -> v2
```

Here I have named the patterns and values to not write them. We now know that `p1` and `p2` must match values of type `a` and that `v1` and `v2` are type `z`. Let’s look at the patterns:

```
| Some state -> ...
| None -> ...
```

So now we can deduce that `a` must be some kind of `option`. Let’s say it is a `b option`. Now we have:

```
extract_x : b option -> z
x : b option
... : z
(In first case only):
  state : b
```

Let’s look at the first case:

```
  | Some state -> state
```

So we now deduce that `z = b`, that is, the type to be returned from this function is the type of `state`, which we called `b`. Let’s look at the other case:

```
  | None -> None
```

Well the value (I.e. the bit after `->`) `None` is an option type. Let’s call this `c option` and we also know that this has to be type `z` so let’s write down what we have so far:

```
extract_x : a -> z
a = b option
z = b
z = c option
```

So we deduce that `b = c option` so `a = c option option` so, marking our arbitrary type variables as polymorphic, we get:

```
extract_x : 'a option option -> 'a option
```

Which is a useful function (called `bind` in general) but not what you want. Here’s how you could write a function with the type `'a option -> 'a`:

```
let extract_x x =
  match x with
  | Some x -> x
  | None -> failwith "extract_x: expected Some"
```

However you probably don’t want this function at all because if you have an option, then it might be `None`, which will cause this function to raise, and if you have an option that is always `Some` then you should try to change your types to express that this thing isn’t optional. Otherwise it may seem that the illegal value `None` is legal because it may be constructed.

Here is how you might actually deal with extracting values from options in a safer way:

```
...
match t.x with
| None -> failwith "invariant for foo violated in bar”
| Some x -> (* carry on *)
  ...

(* don’t do this *)
type 'a one_or_two = 'a option * 'a option
...
  let (first, second) = ... : _ one_or_two in
  match first with
  | None ->
    (* now we know second must be Some *)
    let second = extract_x second in
    ...

(* do this instead *)
type 'a one_or_two = First of 'a | Second of 'a | Both of 'a * 'a
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument x has type 'a option option because extract_x returns either None or the value of state.  This means that 'state' must itself be an option variant.  So x, which you are pattern matching on as an option ('Some state'), must be an option of an option.

To resolve this you need the None case in your pattern match to evaluate to something other than an option, with the same type as 'state'.

Answer (score 0):

It may be instructive to look at how this operation is implemented in the standard library. From [the source](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/option.ml):

> ```ml
> let value o ~default = match o with Some v -> v | None -> default
> let get = function Some v -> v | None -> invalid_arg "option is None"
> ```

Here we see two different ways of handling this. [`Option.value`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Option.html?VALvalue) takes a default value (using a named argument) to return in the event `o` is `None`.

In [`Option.get`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Option.html?VALget) an `Invalid_argument` exception is raised when the argument is `None`.